# Texture bake stuck at 100%

Tags: baking

Hi all first question here, I looked all over the internet but didn't see anything so I signed up here. Im baking a texture, at 400 samples and it took a day to get to 100%. Its been at the 100% done mark for about 6 hours now.Blender is still responding but my texture hasn't finished baking. Im afraid to touch anything. What should I do. The bar is there at 100% with the X. the image i was baking to is still black with the smart project laid out. I did a test bake which turned out fine and went for high quality next. I think blender is just being buggy. I don't know what to do besides hit the x and be disappointed I have to start over. I heard someone got stuck at 50%, reopened the file, and the bake appeared.Sounds to good to be true. Is there a cool recovery mode or save record of what has been done so I don't have to start over? Is there anything I can do besides start hitting x's and closing everything? WHY I was so close.

Comment: things I forgot to mention: Im using blender 2.73 and baking in cycles. My CPU usage seems to be jumping from normal to max on all cores mostly being maxed. blender .exe is also saying its taking between 25 to 100%  on another processor monitor i have (mostly in the high 80%). I think blender is still doing things or trying to do things. No errors have come up either.

Comment: Task manager says I'm using 33% memory and that I have 10.7 GB available so I don't think its a memory thing. I have 3 monitors and was keeping an eye on it over the course of the day and saw it hit 100% over 6 hrs ago. So the bar wasn't acting funny in any way and moved along as it should. I think that's it. Sorry for so many consecutive posts. The character limits and edit times are killin me.

Comment: Hi. You can add more information by using the [edit] link below your question instead of comments.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall and reinstall blender I did that and it worked!